# PyTorch CNN unable to initialize due to excessive memory consumption

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm currently attempting to utilize a convolutional neural network to classify demented and non-demented MRI scans. All of the code shown below has been run on using a Core i7 CPU, 8.00 GB of RAM, and a GTX 1060 GPU. After sifting through journal articles and studies regarding the use of machine learning to conduct similar tasks, I've seen that it will require a highly complex model to see any success. I've attached the code for the CNN below.

```
class Hl_Model(nn.Module):

torch.cuda.set_device(0)

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv6 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv7 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv8 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv9 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, stride=1)
    self.conv10 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, stride=1)
    
    x = torch.randn(216,144).view(-1,1,216,144)
    self._to_linear = None
    self.convs(x)
    
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 512, bias=True)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 128, bias=True)
    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(128, 3)

def convs(self, x):
    
    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2), stride=1)
    x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv4(x)), (2, 2), stride=1)
    x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))
    x = F.relu(self.conv6(x))
    x = F.relu(self.conv7(x))
    x = F.relu(self.conv8(x))
    x = F.relu(self.conv9(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv10(x)), (2,2), stride=1)

    if self._to_linear is None:
        self._to_linear = x[0].shape[0]*x[0].shape[1]*x[0].shape[2]
    return x


def forward(self, x):
    x = self.convs(x)
    x = x.view(-1, self._to_linear)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
    x = self.fc4(x)
    return F.softmax(x, dim=1)
```

When ran, the program quickly fails due to excessive memory consumption and returns the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jack Diskin\Documents\OASIS_CNN.py", line 114, in <module>
    hl_model = Hl_Model()
  File "c:\Users\Jack Diskin\Documents\OASIS_CNN.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 512, bias=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at ..\c10\core\CPUAllocator.cpp:72] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough 
memory: you tried to allocate 24487395328 bytes. Buy new RAM!
```

However, in studies such as "Multi-Grade Brain Tumor Classification using Deep
CNN with Extensive Data Augmentation" (Sajjad et al, 2018), the authors use a significantly more complex architecture with the same 8 GB of RAM possessed by my computer. For this reason, I'm confused as to why my model will not run.

Comment: That's a pretty huge CNN. Even if it would fit into RAM, are you sure you have enough train data and compute time to train such a beast? Why not start with a much smaller network and then gradually explore the performance of larger networks?

Comment: @couka I used data augmentation to create an 111,600 image dataset, with 37,200 images corresponding to each class. My first approach for the model was relatively simple, with only 4 convolutional layers and 2 fully-connected. However, my model appeared to not learn at all from epoch to epoch and would only predict one class, remaining at .666 loss. I tried to slowly scale up, adding roughly 2 convolutional units at a time, but the model continued to see no change in loss or accuracy.